# getting 502 proxy error while parsing

Tags: php, parsing

Iam parsing a page and im getting response from that but after some time i.e. after some of the parsing gets done i get this error from the server -

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /file.php.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

and after this my parsing fails.
I even tried sleep() function but it didnt helped and the error still came.

Are they temporarily blocking my ip or what??
What could be the reason for this and how can i parse those pages without getting this error and all ???

Comment: Your timing may still be too aggressive. Perhaps your access pattern raises some kind of flag or you're hitting a bug in the web app such as a missing item in the database that has never been spotted.

Comment: And from what I understand you are doing more than just _parsing_ but something like web crawling. Or are you re-accessing the same URL each time?

Comment: thats all okay how can i parse this page now??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CURL to fetch the page contents and then parse them? let me know if this works or you need any help.

--Pinaki